# Add a "rank" column to a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with counts of different items, in different years:

```
df <- data.frame(item = rep(c('a','b','c'), 3),
                 year = rep(c('2010','2011','2012'), each=3),
                 count = c(1,4,6,3,8,3,5,7,9))
```

And I would like to add a "year.rank" column, which gives an item's rank within a given year, where a higher count leads to a higher "rank". With the above, it would look like:

```
  item year count year.rank
1    a 2010     1         3
2    b 2010     4         2
3    c 2010     6         1
4    a 2011     3         2
5    b 2011     8         1
6    c 2011     3         3
7    a 2012     5         3
8    b 2012     7         2
9    c 2012     9         1
```

I know I could do this for the whole data frame using `order(df$count)`, but I'm not sure how I would do it by year.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a `rank` function to help you with that:

```
transform(df, 
          year.rank = ave(count, year, 
                          FUN = function(x) rank(-x, ties.method = "first")))
  item year count year.rank
1    a 2010     1         3
2    b 2010     4         2
3    c 2010     6         1
4    a 2011     3         2
5    b 2011     8         1
6    c 2011     3         3
7    a 2012     5         3
8    b 2012     7         2
9    c 2012     9         1
```

Comment: +1 because I tried with rank without succes!! i am stuck with the rank function!

Comment: @agstudy, I had actually originally posted too quickly, without success. The key was the `-x` (since rank usually goes low to high), and `ties.method` (since rank usually defaults to average).

Comment: possibly useful to note that if the `count` variable happened to be a `POSIXlt` variable instead of numeric, you can wrap it in `as.numeric()`

Answer (score 26):

`data.table` version for practice:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[,yrrank:=rank(-count,ties.method="first"),by=year]

   item year count yrrank
1:    a 2010     1      3
2:    b 2010     4      2
3:    c 2010     6      1
4:    a 2011     3      2
5:    b 2011     8      1
6:    c 2011     3      3
7:    a 2012     5      3
8:    b 2012     7      2
9:    c 2012     9      1
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Is there any good documentation anywhere for using the side effects portion of data.table? I've been starting to use it, but am not yet as proficient as I'd like.

Comment: @Wilduck - this isn't so much a side effect as the main effect! I'm pretty new to `data.table` too, but I've just been going through the FAQ at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf Google is your friend!

Comment: By side effect I mean that it's performing an operation on the data.table, rather than returning a separate result. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science) In any case, I appreciate the response.

Comment: data.table 1.9.6 function now called frank or frankv, very helpful

Answer (score 10):

Using `order` function,

```
transform(dat, x= ave(count,year,FUN=function(x) order(x,decreasing=T)))
  item year count x
1    a 2010     1 3
2    b 2010     4 2
3    c 2010     6 1
4    a 2011     3 2
5    b 2011     8 1
6    c 2011     3 3
7    a 2012     5 3
8    b 2012     7 2
9    c 2012     9 1
```

**EDIT**

You can use `plyr` here also:

```
ddply(dat,.(year),transform,x =  order(count,decreasing=T))
```

Comment: I love a cleaner solution, I find it better to do `ave()` than `ave(rank())` but in this case you'd have no control over `ties.method`, right?

Answer (score 9):

Using **dplyr** you could do it as follows:

```
library(dplyr) # 0.4.1
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(yrrank = row_number(-count))

#Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
#Groups: year
#
#  item year count yrrank
#1    a 2010     1      3
#2    b 2010     4      2
#3    c 2010     6      1
#4    a 2011     3      2
#5    b 2011     8      1
#6    c 2011     3      3
#7    a 2012     5      3
#8    b 2012     7      2
#9    c 2012     9      1
```

It is the same as:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(yrrank = rank(-count, ties.method = "first"))
```

Note that the resulting data is still grouped by "year". If you want to remove the grouping you can simply extend the pipe with `%>% ungroup()`.

Answer (score 1):

While using the answers given by others, I found that the following performs faster than the *transform* and *dyplr* variants:

```
df$year.rank <- ave(count, year, FUN = function(x) rank(-x, ties.method = "first"))
```