# How to refer to multiple variables with a common prefix using a placeholder in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data.frame:

```
x.a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y.b <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
y.c <- c(5,1,0,9,2)
y.d <- c(5,6,7,3,1)
x.e <- c(2,6,1,2,3)

df <- data.frame(x.a,y.b,y.c,y.d,x.e)
```

Suppose I want to rank the variables y.b, y.c, y.d:

```
df[2:4] <- sapply(df[2:4], function(x) rank(x))
```

Is there a way to apply a function to all variables with the prefix `y.`? E.g.:

```
df[y.*] <- sapply(df[y.*], function(x) rank(x))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `grep` and regular expression, like this :

```
df <- data.frame(x.a,y.b,y.c,y.d,x.e)
df[, grep("y\\..", names(df))]
  y.b y.c y.d
1   2   5   5
2   3   1   6
3   4   0   7
4   5   9   3
5   6   2   1
```

You have to escape the `.` in the variable name, the second `.` is for matching everything.

Comment: Thanks! Today is a good day learning R - 3rd question I got an answer for :)