# How to create new variables with a suffix from an operation on a set of variables addressed by grep() using a prefix in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908903/how-to-refer-to-multiple-variables-with-a-common-prefix-using-a-placeholder-in-r):

Suppose I have a data.frame:

```
x.a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y.b <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
y.c <- c(5,1,0,9,2)
y.d <- c(5,6,7,3,1)
x.e <- c(2,6,1,2,3)

df <- data.frame(x.a,y.b,y.c,y.d,x.e)
```

Suppose I want to rank all variables with the prefix `y.`

```
df[, grep("y\\..", names(df))] <- sapply(df[, grep("y\\..", names(df))], function(x) rank(x))
```

How can I, instead of replacing the old values in the variables with their rank, create a new variable with a new *suffix*? I.e. to end up with the data.frame:

```
  x.a y.b y.c y.d x.e y.b.ranked y.c.ranked y.d.ranked
   1   2   5   5   2       1         4          3
   2   3   1   6   6       2         2          4
   3   4   0   7   1       3         1          5
   4   5   9   3   2       4         5          2
   5   6   2   1   3       5         3          1
```

Comment: `cbind(df, sapply(...))`? However, I'd suggest to change your data format to "long format". That would make things easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1=sapply(df[, grep("y\\..", names(df))], function(x) rank(x))

colnames(df1)=paste(colnames(df1),'ranked',sep=".")

df=cbind(df,df1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was apparently overthinking it trying to forge something special with the assginment.