# Add a column to a data frame that index the number of occurrences in a group

Tags: r, indexing, row, grouping

Given data frame like this

```
 Unit    Anything
 A       3.4
 A1      2.2
 A       6.9
 A1      1.1
 B       2
 B       3
```

Sort by anything, group by unit, add an index

```
 Unit    Anything   Index
 A       3.4         1
 A1      2.2         2
 A       6.9         2
 A1      1.1         1
 B       2           1
 B       3           2
```

I know `df[order(df$Anything),]` orders by `Anything`.
But I can't get a count to work.  I tried stuff like

```
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,count := .N, by = list(Unit)]
```

Comment: One way would be to first order ``df`` by ``Unit`` and then use ``tapply``, like ``d$Index <- do.call(c, tapply(d$Unit, d$Unit, function(x) 1:length(x)))``.

Comment: @parsimoni  Thanks, this runs pretty quick.

Comment: d$Index <- do.call(c, tapply(d$Unit, d$Unit, function(x) 1:length(x)))  does not make Index column properly. Check by d[order(d$Unit,d$Anything),] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the related topics, by trial and error, the following seems to work....
ref: [Add a "rank" column to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame?rq=1)

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
 Unit    Anything
 A       3.4
 A1      2.2
 A       6.9
 A1      1.1
 B       2
 B       3
")

df <- transform(df, x= ave(Anything,Unit,FUN=function(x) order(x,decreasing=F)))

df
  Unit Anything x
1    A      3.4 1
2   A1      2.2 2
3    A      6.9 2
4   A1      1.1 1
5    B      2.0 1
6    B      3.0 2
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered multiple times. When you found the answer in "related topics" you probably should have either left a link for the duplicate and/or deleted it.

Comment: This answer doesn't work because the Anything column consists of dates.

Comment: If it's not an answer then you should a) delete it, and b) edit your question to create an example that has dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
ddf = structure(list(Unit = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"A1", "B"), class = "factor"), Anything = c(3.4, 2.2, 6.9, 1.1, 
2, 3)), .Names = c("Unit", "Anything"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ddf2 = ddf[order(ddf$Unit, ddf$Anything),]
ddf2$index = 0

for(U in unique(ddf$Unit)){
    ddf2[ddf2$Unit==U,]$index = 1:length(ddf2[ddf2$Unit==U,]$Unit)
}

ddf2
  Unit Anything index
1    A      3.4     1
3    A      6.9     2
4   A1      1.1     1
2   A1      2.2     2
5    B      2.0     1
6    B      3.0     2
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I should have made the example more similar to my actual problem.  There are 113000 rows, and about 500 unit numbers, and the order by quantity is a date value (which is not an issue in your solution).  Your solution took about 3 minutes to run.  My solution, below, doesn't work on dates.

Comment: You should tick on upvote/accept for answers that are helpful.

Comment: use: ddf2=data.table(ddf2) and try solution given on this link instead of 'for' loop above. It is likely to be faster. Let us know the result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532844/filling-up-index-column-in-data-table