# Filling up index column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This question is related to: [Add a column to a data frame that index the number of occurrences in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516365/add-a-column-to-a-data-frame-that-index-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-group)
I have following data.table sorted by first 2 columns.

```
ddt = structure(list(Unit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"A1", "B"), class = "factor"), Anything = c(3.4, 6.9, 1.1, 2.2, 
2, 3), index = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Unit", "Anything", 
"index"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x8948f68>, sorted = c("Unit", 
"Anything"))

ddt
   Unit Anything index
1:    A      3.4     0
2:    A      6.9     0
3:   A1      1.1     0
4:   A1      2.2     0
5:    B      2.0     0
6:    B      3.0     0
```

The index column is to be filled by 1,2,3...  for each Unit. For a data.frame I can do it by :

```
for(U in unique(ddt$Unit)){
    ddt[ddt$Unit==U,]$index = 1:length(ddt[ddt$Unit==U,]$Unit)
}

ddt
  Unit Anything index
1    A      3.4     1
3    A      6.9     2
4   A1      1.1     1
2   A1      2.2     2
5    B      2.0     1
6    B      3.0     2
```

But how to do it using data.table commands? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 ddt[, indx:=1:.N, by=Unit]
 #     Unit Anything indx
 #1:    A      3.4    1
 #2:    A      6.9    2
 #3:   A1      1.1    1
 #4:   A1      2.2    2
 #5:    B      2.0    1
 #6:    B      3.0    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ddt[, index := as.numeric(seq_len(.N)), by="Unit"]
ddt

   Unit Anything index
1:    A      3.4     1
2:    A      6.9     2
3:   A1      1.1     1
4:   A1      2.2     2
5:    B      2.0     1
6:    B      3.0     2
```

Comment: use `.N` instead of that `length` contraption

Comment: @ eddi: Can you please enter this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you can't change the class of a column using `:=` (since index is type `double` and ideally you want integers). I would recommend removing `index` and recreating it with `:=`:

```
ddt$index = NULL
ddt[,index:= 1:nrow(.SD), by=Unit]
> ddt
   Unit Anything index
1:    A      3.4     1
2:    A      6.9     2
3:   A1      1.1     1
4:   A1      2.2     2
5:    B      2.0     1
6:    B      3.0     2
```