# R data table: compare row value to group values

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to compare the value of each row to the values of the group.

For example, I start with:

```
x = data.table( id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), price=c(100,110,120,100,100,120) )
> x
   id price
1:  1   100
2:  1   110
3:  1   120
4:  2   100
5:  2   100
6:  2   120
```

and would like to arrive to:

```
> x
   id price nb_cheaper_prices_per_id
1:  1   100                        0
2:  1   110                        1
3:  1   120                        2
4:  2   100                        0
5:  2   100                        0
6:  2   120                        2
```

I tried:

```
x[, sum(price<.SD[,price]), by=id]
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x[,cheaper := floor(rank(price))-1, by=id]
#    id price cheaper
# 1:  1   100       0
# 2:  1   110       1
# 3:  1   120       2
# 4:  2   100       0
# 5:  2   100       0
# 6:  2   120       2
```

`?rank` will rank the values in each group. I added `?floor` to cancel the effects of the handling of ties. A second option is to use `ties.method="min"`. Lastly, `1` is subtracted from the ranks to start at 0.

Comment: Or my namesake: `x[, n_cheaper := frank(price, ties.method="dense")-1L, by=id]` or `x[order(price), n_cheaper := rleid(price)-1L, by=id]`.

Comment: This works for the example, but I am not sure this will work in all cases.  Also, the OP's description is different.

Comment: @akrun they ask to "compare the value of each row to the values of the group". That's what rank is doing there.

Comment: Ok, I thought the OP wanted to compare with the full price column

Comment: I like the `frank` approach too. OP can choose from all.

Comment: If you are finding duplicates for the one I posted, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame) is close enough as a dupe of this post