# R data table: compare row value to group values, with condition

Tags: r, data.table

This is a prolongation of the question:

[R data table: compare row value to group values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285050/r-data-table-compare-row-value-to-group-values)

I have now:

```
x = data.table( id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), price = c(10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 
8, 11), subgroup = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))

   id price subgroup
1:  1    10        1
2:  1    10        1
3:  1    12        1
4:  1    12        1
5:  1    12        1
6:  1    15        1
7:  1     8        2
8:  1    11        2
```

and would like to calculate the number of rows with lower prices per id, but *only counting the ones in subgroup 1*.

If I use:

```
x[,cheaper := rank(price, ties.method="min")-1, by=id]
```

the results is:

```
> x
   id price subgroup cheaper
1:  1    10        1       1   # only 1 is cheaper (row 7)
2:  1    10        1       1   # only 1 is cheaper (row 7)
3:  1    12        1       4   # 4 frows are cheaper (row 1,2,7,8)
4:  1    12        1       4   # etc
5:  1    12        1       4
6:  1    15        1       7
7:  1     8        2       0
8:  1    11        2       3
```

but I would like the result to be:

```
> x
   id price subgroup cheaper_in_subgroup_1
1:  1    10        1       0    # nobody in subgroup 1 is cheaper
2:  1    10        1       0    # nobody in subgroup 1 is cheaper
3:  1    12        1       2    # only row 1 and 2 are cheaper in subgroup 1
4:  1    12        1       2
5:  1    12        1       2
6:  1    15        1       5
7:  1     8        2       0    # nobody in subgroup 1 is cheaper
8:  1    11        2       2    # only row 1 and 2 are cheaper in subgroup 1
```

Comment: I think your last row is incorrect, as you supposed to compare per subgroup, no? I was thinking something like `x[, cheaper := sapply(price, function(x) sum(price < x)), by = .(id, subgroup)]` but I'm not sure I fully understand your logic

Comment: @DavidArenburg No I do not wish to compare within subgroups. I wish to compare all rows to subgroup 1. I know it's not the usual way, but that's what I need.

Comment: Ok, does this work `x[, cheaper := sapply(price, function(x) sum(price[subgroup == 1] < x)), by = id]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, that looks very good so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more `data.table`ish way achieving this, but here an attempt using `vapply` within each `id`

```
x[, cheaper := vapply(price, 
                      function(x) sum(price[subgroup == 1L] < x),
                      FUN.VALUE = integer(1L)), 
               by = id]
x
#    id price subgroup cheaper
# 1:  1    10        1       0
# 2:  1    10        1       0
# 3:  1    12        1       2
# 4:  1    12        1       2
# 5:  1    12        1       2
# 6:  1    15        1       5
# 7:  1     8        2       0
# 8:  1    11        2       2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using a little trick with *rolling joins*:

```
y = x[subgroup==1L, .N, keyby=.(id, price+1L)][, N := cumsum(N)][]
#    id price N
# 1:  1    11 2
# 2:  1    13 5
# 3:  1    16 6
x[, cheaper := y[x, N, roll=TRUE, rollends=FALSE, on=c("id", "price")]]
#    id price subgroup cheaper
# 1:  1    10        1      NA
# 2:  1    10        1      NA
# 3:  1    12        1       2
# 4:  1    12        1       2
# 5:  1    12        1       2
# 6:  1    15        1       5
# 7:  1     8        2      NA
# 8:  1    11        2       2
```

The idea is to get the cumulative sum for each `id,price`, but store it for `price+1L`. This'll result in values in `x` obtaining the count corresponding to the last observation while performing a rolling join.

---

PS: If `price` is not an *integer* type, then it'd be `price * (1 + eps)` instead of `price + 1L` when obtaining `y`.

Comment: Nice, I was trying to do something using rolling joins but didn't have enough brains I guess.