# Hadoop query to compare row value to group values, with condition

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I wish to port some R code to Hadoop to be used with Impala or Hive with a SQL-like query.
The code I have is based on this question:

[R data table: compare row value to group values, with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343433/r-data-table-compare-row-value-to-group-values-with-condition/33343925#33343925)

The point si to find, for each row, the number of rows with the same id in subgroup 1 with cheaper price.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE project
(
    id int,
    price int, 
    subgroup int
);

INSERT INTO project(id,price,subgroup) 
VALUES
    (1, 10, 1), 
    (1, 10, 1), 
    (1, 12, 1),
    (1, 15, 1),
    (1,  8, 2),
    (1, 11, 2),
    (2,  9, 1),
    (2, 12, 1),
    (2, 14, 2),
    (2, 18, 2);
```

Now the following query works fine in Impala for the row in subgroup 1:

```
select *, rank() over (partition by id order by price asc) - 1 as cheaper
from project
where subgroup = 1
```

but I need to also take care of the rows in subgroup 2.

So the output I wish to have is:

```
id  price   subgroup   cheaper
1   10      1          0 ( because no row is cheaper in id 1 subgroup 1)
1   10      1          0 ( because no row is cheaper in id 1 subgroup 1)
1   12      1          2 ( rows 1 and 2 are cheaper)
1   15      1          3
1    8      2          0 (nobody is cheaper in id 1 and subgroup 1)
1   11      2          2
2    9      1          0
2   12      1          1
2   14      2          2
2   18      2          2
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into basically the exact same problem awhile back.  It's like you need a windowing function that you can put a `where` clause in.  To get around this I collected price to an array (where subgroup = 1) and self-joined the table.  Then I wrote a UDF to filter an array given a predicate.

**UDF**:

```
package somepkg;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FilterArrayUDF extends UDF {
    public ArrayList<Integer> evaluate(ArrayList<Text> arr, int p) {
        ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            int elem = Integer.parseInt((arr.get(i)).toString());
            if (elem < p)
                newList.add(elem);
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Then when you have the filtered array, you can just take the size of it.

**Query**:

```
add jar /path/to/jars/hive-udfs.jar;
create temporary function filter_arr as 'somepkg.FilterArrayUDF';

select B.id, price, subgroup, price_arr
  , filter_arr(price_arr, price) cheaper_arr
  , size(filter_arr(price_arr, price)) cheaper
from db.tbl B
join (
  select id, collect_list(price) price_arr
  from db.tbl
  where subgroup = 1
  group by id ) A
on B.id = A.id
```

**Output**:

```
1    10    1    [10,10,12,15]    []               0
1    10    1    [10,10,12,15]    []               0
1    12    1    [10,10,12,15]    [10,10]          2
1    15    1    [10,10,12,15]    [10,10,12]       3
1    8     2    [10,10,12,15]    []               0
1    11    2    [10,10,12,15]    [10,10]          2
2    9     1    [9,12]           []               0
2    12    1    [9,12]           [9]              1
2    14    2    [9,12]           [9,12]           2
2    18    2    [9,12]           [9,12]           2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following query:-

```
select * from 
    (
    select *, rank() over (partition by id order by price asc) - 1 as cheaper
    from project
    where subgroup = 1 union
    select *, rank() over (partition by id order by price asc) - 1 as cheaper
    from project
    where subgroup = 2) result
```

Comment: thanks but this is not what I want: I want to compare even those in subgroup 2 to the prices in subgroup 1. So every row (no matter in which subgroup) will be compared to all prices in subgroup 2.