# R data.table, mean number of instances of factor variable, grouped by two other factor variables

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I'm attempting to use ddply to work with a data.table(dt1).  As an example dt1 is comprised of three, factor columns.  What I need to do is create a fourth numeric column, that has calculated the mean number of incidences of a "1" in the "pres" column, by combination of "walk" and "date".

```
dt1 <- data.table (walk = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=12)),
               date = as.factor(rep(1:4, 9)),
               pres = as.factor(rbinom(36,1,0.5))
               )
```

creates a data table like this

```
> head (dt1)
   walk date pres
1:    1    1    0
2:    1    1    0
3:    1    1    1
4:    1    2    1
5:    1    2    1
6:    1    2    1
```

and what I hope to end up with is like this

```
> head (dt1)
   walk date pres  mean
1:    1    1    0   0.33
2:    1    1    0   0.33
3:    1    1    1   0.33
4:    1    2    1   1.00
5:    1    2    1   1.00
6:    1    2    1   1.00
```

I'm attempting to use the ddply function and think I'm close but have not got the function part correct yet

```
ddply(dt1, .variables=c("walk","date"), .fun = sum(dt1[, pres] == "1") / length(dt1[,pres])) [ , ]
```

Any suggestions on how to set the formula correctly, or alternatively a better solution, most welcome.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to create a reproducible example.

Comment: Prolly best to use data.table to work with a data.table, not plyr. If you want to mix hadleyverse packages (which plyr falls into) with data.tables, try dplyr, which boasts nice integration with data.table.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Not an exact, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame) could be one (just like this was closed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We group by 'walk', 'date', create a new column 'Mean' by assigning (`:=`) the output of `mean` from the logical index `pres==1`.

```
 dt1[, Mean := mean(pres==1) , by=.(walk, date)]
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can `sum` the logical index and divide by number of rows (`.N`)

```
 dt1[, Mean := sum(pres==1)/.N, by = .(walk, date)]
```

---

As the OP used `ddply`, the equivalent option would be

```
 library(plyr)
 ddply(dt1, .variables=c('walk', 'date'),  mutate, Mean= mean(pres==1))
```

Or if we are using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 dt1 %>%
    group_by(walk, date) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Mean= mean(pres==1))
```

---

A `base R` option would be

```
dt1$Mean <- with(dt1, ave(pres==1, walk, date))
```

Comment: @user207146  Glad to help you.  Thanks for the feedback.