# Adding tapply to a column

Tags: r, tapply

I have a data frame with 2 columns: 'sales' and 'month'. I want to add a column that ranks the sales within each month. Does anyone know what's the most succinct way of doing so? I'm thinking of 'tapply' but it gives me a list and I can't add it back to the data frame (easily or succinctly).

```
Sales Month      Rank
100   1          3
200   2          1
300   3          1
150   1          2
220   1          1

100 is third place amongst sales that belong to month 1 while 220 is first place for month 1.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a "rank" column to a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ave` from `base R` to create the column

```
df1$Rank <- with(df1, ave(-Sales, Month, FUN = rank))
df1$Rank
#[1] 3 1 1 2 1
```

---

Or another succinct and efficient option is `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Month', we assign (`:=`) the `rank` of 'Sales' to create 'Rank'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Rank := rank(-Sales) , Month]
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Or simply use `DT[, mrank := rank(-Sales), by=Month]`.

Comment: @SunBee Yes, you meant `DT <- as.data.table(df1)` right?

Comment: You are right. The cast to data.table is required. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(sales=c(100, 200, 300, 150, 220), month=c(1,2,3,1,1))
df %>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(rank(desc(sales)))
```

Though I think the quetion is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15170777/3871924)