# how i can give datagridview column value

Tags: c#

[image: Datagrid]
I want to give the datagridview invoiceno column the same value when the containingno column have the same value.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dgvDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value = invNo;
                    dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value = DAL.ShippingInvoicesSold_dal.ShippingInvoiceName(invNo);
                }
                else
                {
                    invNo = invNo + 1;
                    dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value = invNo;
                    dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value = DAL.ShippingInvoicesSold_dal.ShippingInvoiceName(invNo);

                }
            }
```

Comment: So in your example, both values in containingno are 4, so you would want both corresponding  values invoiceno to be 5. Is this correct?

Comment: Your code could be very much simplified, as the rows updates are the same its the inv number that change.s

Comment: Please try using the data table version of rank [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame)

Comment: yes that i want exactly Sudsy1002